# Get a series of Averages, of 10 numbers, from a much larger set

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very large set of historical stock price data (> 4 mil records in a CSV)
These are read in using VBA code.

I would like to compute stats (like a Moving Average).
This is the average of the last 10 numbers read in - using VBA.
Then write that number to my XLS (or back to the CSV)

Ex.  read in 10 numbers, calculate, write
Read in the next row, and do it all over again.

What is a computationally effecient solution for this?

I thought of reading in, storing the last 10 in an array, get the stat.
But there seems to be no way to remove the first value from an array.

Thanks

Comment: Declare a variable to hold the total, and initialize it to zero. In a loop, read however many lines as you want, adding each value read to that total variable. When you've reached the end of the loop, divide the total by the number of rows you read to get the average and write it to the sheet. Reset the total variable to 0 and repeat the process until you've read all the rows.

Comment: `Dim Rng As Range, Arr As Variant`
`Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(11, "A"): Arr=Rng.Value`
`Set Rng = Range(Cells(12, "A"), Cells(21, "A"): Arr=Rng.Value`
The value of array Arr will change with each iteration.